# Bind to jquery function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm using JQuery inside EcmaScript 6 class, and I have an event function which fires on instantiation of the class and the event contains different JQuery events which need to interact with the Class , so I do .bind() to achieve that, all works ok except one event which for some reason overrides this that belongs to jquery element "this" with "that" which I passed with .bind(that) method, here is my code (everything works exept for this event) :

```
var that = this;
$(document).on('click', '[select-file]' , function(event) {
event.preventDefault();


console.log(this);

}.bind(that));
```

so the console log gives me the parent class instead of jquery element 
where as this works as expected:

```
            $(document).on('click', '[open-file-dialoge]', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                  $('[file-dialoge]').modal('show');
                  if ($(this).attr('mitiupload') == 'false') {
                    // check if multiple upload is disabled
                    that.multiUpload = false;
                    $(this).removeAttr('multiple');
                  }
                  that.insertFiles();
            }.bind(that));
```

Pleas help , I can't understand what is going on here one does not work as expected even though there is no big difference between them ;(

Comment: Just use `that` for the parent scope and leave jQuery to assign its own `this`.

Comment: Don't see how it's possible for the second one to work for `$(this)`

Comment: Why do you use `bind` at all if you don't want `this` to refer to the class instance but the element?!

Comment: charlietfl, it actually does not work as well, my bad , I didn't notice coz it didn't give me errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Function#bind()` changes the context of `this` in a function. If you want the current element you can use `event.currentTarget`

```js
var that = {};
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var el = event.currentTarget;

  console.log('this=', this);
  console.log('el=', el)

}.bind(that));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Click me</button>
```